# what is the c/c++ virtual machine referred to in the asm.js spec

Tags: c++, c, vm-implementation, asm.js

In the spec for asm.js (at http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/ ) in the introduction section it says

"The asm.js language provides an abstraction similar to the C/C++ virtual machine"

..but I can't find any information on 'the C/C++ virtual machine' by googling. Can someone enlighten me or point me in the direction of a book/website which describes 'the c/c++ virtual machine'

Comment: C and C++ uses the phrase "abstract machine" rather than "virtual machine". That'll hopefully improve your googling from ending up reading about vmware or java.

Comment: They've probably just got their terminology mixed up.

Comment: There are email addresses at the top of the document. @AlonZakai is [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1176841/alon-zakai) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok will drop him a message, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) talks about an abstract machine it makes assumptions about. I suppose that is what the author of `asm.js` talks about.

Comment: C/C++ is no virtual machine - they are defined programming languages. You may build a virtual machine on top of them (eg.: geordi)

Comment: @DieterLücking: You're winning no converts here.  You see, the thing that glglgl did that you failed to, is that he tried to understand what the OP really wanted to know, and he provided that information.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley what is a OP? Yep I failed !

Comment: @DieterLücking: OP = Original Poster.  The person who made the first post.  On stack overflow, this means the person who asked the question.  In this case, James Cat.

Comment: thanks, yes. now I understand it should be abstract machine, makes sense like 'stack-machine', or 'register-machine' - that sort of concept. That is very helpful. (also don't take it badly Dieter, that's just the way the StackOverflow cookie crumbles)